# Encapsulates a C-style Buffer

Tags: c++, string, oop

I have the code below to illustrate C style strings. This piece of code is only for illustration. The constructor initialize the instance correctly, but when reading MyString nonsense comes back. Can anyone suggest or explain what is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyString
{
private:
    char* Buffer;
public:
    //Constructor
    MyString(const char* InitialInput)
    {
        char* Buffer = new char [4];    // Only three characters are allowed!
                                        // It must end with '\0' or it is not a string
        for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i){
            Buffer[i]=InitialInput[i];
        }
        Buffer[3]='\0';                 // Now it is a string.

        cout << "Constructed the string: " << Buffer << endl;

    }

    void ShowString()
    {
        cout << "This is the string: " << Buffer << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyString line1("abc"); // Only three characters are allowed!
    MyString line2("def");

    cout << endl << "MyString objects: " << endl;
    line1.ShowString();
    line2.ShowString();


    return 0;
}
```

This is what comes back on the screen

Constructed the string: abc

Constructed the string: def

MyString objects:

This is the string: ƒÄ[Ã1Ûë‰Ã?C‹…°)@

This is the string: ”ÿ(

Comment: destructors are your friend, don't leak memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the `char *Buffer` in local scope of the constructer. Hence instead of using the data member, the local variable is used. Here is the corrected code

```
class MyString
{
private:
    char* Buffer;
public:
    //Constructor
    MyString(const char* InitialInput)
    {
        //char* Buffer -> dont define here. If defined, this definition
        //will hide the data member defintion
        Buffer = new char [4];    // Only three characters are allowed!
                                        // It must end with '\0' or it is not a string
        for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i){
            Buffer[i]=InitialInput[i];
        }
        Buffer[3]='\0';                 // Now it is a string.

        cout << "Constructed the string: " << Buffer << endl;

    }

    void ShowString()
    {
        cout << "This is the string: " << Buffer << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyString line1("abc"); // Only three characters are allowed!
    MyString line2("def");

    cout << endl << "MyString objects: " << endl;
    line1.ShowString();
    line2.ShowString();


    return 0;
}
```